# Can't see Istio metrics in Apache SkyWalking

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, jaeger, distributed-tracing

Couldn't see in `skywalking ui` data from `istio` metrics.

Using below guide to installed `istio` and `skywalking` backend to `Kubernetes`:
https://github.com/apache/skywalking/tree/master/docs/en/setup/istio.
Made all steps in the guide and deployed app. Deployed app is example `book app` from `istio`. Could see traces in `Jaeger` and works good, but can't see `istio` metrics in `skywalking ui`.

How I can provide metrics from `istio` to `skywalking ui` or what I need to configure to make metrics from `istio` come to `skywalking ui`.

Mixer logs:

```
gc 1847 @19617.610s 0%: 0.043+22+0.035 ms clock, 0.17+1.9/28/17+0.14 ms cpu, 16->16->8 MB, 17 MB goal, 6 P
2019-10-11T01:28:44.153821Z warn    grpcAdapter unable to connect to:/metric.HandleMetricService/HandleMetric, oap.skywalking.svc.cluster.local:11800
{"level":"info","time":"2019-10-11T01:28:43.143390Z","instance":"accesslog.instance.istio-system","apiClaims":"","apiKey":"","clientTraceId":"","connection_security_policy":"none","destinationApp":"telemetry","destinationIp":"10.1.3.13","destinationName":"istio-telemetry-7c88764b9c-fncph","destinationNamespace":"istio-system","destinationOwner":"kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/istio-telemetry","destinationPrincipal":"","destinationServiceHost":"istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local","destinationWorkload":"istio-telemetry","grpcMessage":"3 errors occurred:%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%0A","grpcStatus":"2","httpAuthority":"mixer","latency":"6.5979ms","method":"POST","permissiveResponseCode":"none","permissiveResponsePolicyID":"none","protocol":"http","receivedBytes":1317,"referer":"","reporter":"destination","requestId":"b45592ff-0c49-49fd-af64-3c9229b60466","requestSize":931,"requestedServerName":"","responseCode":200,"responseFlags":"-","responseSize":0,"responseTimestamp":"2019-10-11T01:28:43.149845Z","sentBytes":421,"sourceApp":"elasticsearch","sourceIp":"10.1.3.36","sourceName":"skywalking-elasticsearch-data-1","sourceNamespace":"default","sourceOwner":"kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/statefulsets/skywalking-elasticsearch-data","sourcePrincipal":"","sourceWorkload":"skywalking-elasticsearch-data","url":"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report","userAgent":"","xForwardedFor":"10.1.3.36"}
{"level":"info","time":"2019-10-11T01:28:43.913917Z","instance":"accesslog.instance.istio-system","apiClaims":"","apiKey":"","clientTraceId":"","connection_security_policy":"none","destinationApp":"telemetry","destinationIp":"10.1.3.13","destinationName":"istio-telemetry-7c88764b9c-fncph","destinationNamespace":"istio-system","destinationOwner":"kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/istio-telemetry","destinationPrincipal":"","destinationServiceHost":"istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local","destinationWorkload":"istio-telemetry","grpcMessage":"1 error occurred:%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%0A","grpcStatus":"2","httpAuthority":"mixer","latency":"13.906ms","method":"POST","permissiveResponseCode":"none","permissiveResponsePolicyID":"none","protocol":"http","receivedBytes":698,"referer":"","reporter":"destination","requestId":"ff7ae8af-f279-46b3-ae86-bde2b61477dd","requestSize":312,"requestedServerName":"","responseCode":200,"responseFlags":"-","responseSize":0,"responseTimestamp":"2019-10-11T01:28:43.927780Z","sentBytes":247,"sourceApp":"elasticsearch","sourceIp":"10.1.3.37","sourceName":"skywalking-elasticsearch-master-2","sourceNamespace":"default","sourceOwner":"kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/statefulsets/skywalking-elasticsearch-master","sourcePrincipal":"","sourceWorkload":"skywalking-elasticsearch-master","url":"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report","userAgent":"","xForwardedFor":"10.1.3.37"}
{"level":"info","time":"2019-10-11T01:28:43.913675Z","instance":"accesslog.instance.istio-system","apiClaims":"","apiKey":"","clientTraceId":"","connection_security_policy":"none","destinationApp":"telemetry","destinationIp":"10.1.3.13","destinationName":"istio-telemetry-7c88764b9c-fncph","destinationNamespace":"istio-system","destinationOwner":"kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/istio-telemetry","destinationPrincipal":"","destinationServiceHost":"istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local","destinationWorkload":"istio-telemetry","grpcMessage":"8 errors occurred:%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%09* fieldEncoder: dimensions - fieldEncoder: value - lookup failed: 'response.time'%0A%0A","grpcStatus":"2","httpAuthority":"mixer","latency":"29.8101ms","method":"POST","permissiveResponseCode":"none","permissiveResponsePolicyID":"none","protocol":"http","receivedBytes":2430,"referer":"","reporter":"destination","requestId":"b0eec606-c91e-4193-aba2-39b069b76474","requestSize":2044,"requestedServerName":"","responseCode":200,"responseFlags":"-","responseSize":0,"responseTimestamp":"2019-10-11T01:28:43.943383Z","sentBytes":857,"sourceApp":"elasticsearch","sourceIp":"10.1.3.37","sourceName":"skywalking-elasticsearch-master-2","sourceNamespace":"default","sourceOwner":"kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/statefulsets/skywalking-elasticsearch-master","sourcePrincipal":"","sourceWorkload":"skywalking-elasticsearch-master","url":"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report","userAgent":"","xForwardedFor":"10.1.3.37"}
2019-10-11T01:28:44.154193Z error   api Report failed: 1 error occurred:
    * rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup oap.skywalking.svc.cluster.local on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host"
```

Istio policy:

```
GC forced
gc 181 @20366.930s 0%: 3.9+19+0.030 ms clock, 15+0/30/67+0.12 ms cpu, 13->13->7 MB, 15 MB goal, 6 P
scvg135: 0 MB released
scvg135: inuse: 15, idle: 43, sys: 58, released: 3, consumed: 55 (MB)
2019-10-11T01:42:28.493381Z info    base.baseBalancer: handle SubConn state change: 0xc0011280a0, CONNECTING
2019-10-11T01:42:28.493442Z info    roundrobinPicker: newPicker called with readySCs: map[]
2019-10-11T01:42:28.577142Z info    grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {oap.skywalking.svc.cluster.local:11800 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup oap.skywalking.svc.cluster.local on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host". Reconnecting...
2019-10-11T01:42:28.577256Z info    base.baseBalancer: handle SubConn state change: 0xc0011280a0, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
GC forced
gc 182 @20486.971s 0%: 0.13+13+0.056 ms clock, 0.55+0/13/26+0.22 ms cpu, 13->13->7 MB, 15 MB goal, 6 P
```

somehow I have failed to connect to my `skywalking` backend, problem was with name and namespace but still getting error but now `skywalking` backend getting data but ui no updates. `Istio` telemetry:

`rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation how to set up `skywalking` properly:
https://github.com/apache/skywalking/issues/3589#issuecomment-543268029